# Add class to parent and child SVG elements

Tags: jquery, svg

I need to iterate over multiple path containers `<g>`, and add a unique class to each one, then for each of the paths inside the container I need to add a unique class.

This is my output:

```
<svg>
  <g>
    <path class="active" fill="#1f77b4" d="M1.0715305595945801e-14,-175A175,175 0 0,1 151.55444566227678,87.49999999999997L138.5640646055102,79.99999999999997A160,160 0 0,0 9.796850830579018e-15,-160Z"></path>
    <path class="active" fill="#aec7e8" d="M151.55444566227678,87.49999999999997A175,175 0 0,1 -151.55444566227675,87.50000000000006L-138.56406460551017,80.00000000000006A160,160 0 0,0 138.5640646055102,79.99999999999997Z"></path>
    <path class="active" fill="#ff7f0e" d="M-151.55444566227675,87.50000000000006A175,175 0 0,1 -3.21459167878374e-14,-175L-2.9390552491737054e-14,-160A160,160 0 0,0 -138.56406460551017,80.00000000000006Z"></path>
  </g>
  <g>
    <path class="active" fill="#1f77b4" d="M1.0715305595945801e-14,-175A175,175 0 0,1 151.55444566227678,87.49999999999997L138.5640646055102,79.99999999999997A160,160 0 0,0 9.796850830579018e-15,-160Z"></path>
    <path class="active" fill="#aec7e8" d="M151.55444566227678,87.49999999999997A175,175 0 0,1 -151.55444566227675,87.50000000000006L-138.56406460551017,80.00000000000006A160,160 0 0,0 138.5640646055102,79.99999999999997Z"></path>
    <path class="active" fill="#ff7f0e" d="M-151.55444566227675,87.50000000000006A175,175 0 0,1 -3.21459167878374e-14,-175L-2.9390552491737054e-14,-160A160,160 0 0,0 -138.56406460551017,80.00000000000006Z"></path>
  </g>
</svg>
```

I can do the following:

```
$.each(path, function(i,elem) {
    $(elem).parent('g').attr('class','active' + i);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested Code:
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hardiksondagar/3mXqf/)

```
$("g").each(function(i,elem)
{

       $(elem).attr('class','class'+i);

       $(elem).find("path").each(function(i,child)
          {
              $(child).attr('class','class'+i);
          });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to use [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/). This will work for arrays []. According to docs,

> A generic iterator function, which can be used to seamlessly iterate over both objects and arrays. **Arrays and array-like objects** with a length property (such as a function's arguments object) are iterated by numeric index, from 0 to length-1. Other objects are iterated via their named properties.

For DOM elements, you need to use [`$("selector").each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/). According to docs,

> Iterate **over a jQuery object**, executing a function for each matched element.

And more :

> The $.each() function is not the same as $(selector).each(), which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object.

So, you have to do it this way :

```
$("path").each( function(i) {
    $(this).attr("class","yourClass").parent('g').attr('class','active' + i);
});
```

To access the current element, you need to use `$(this)`.

Comment: What about the child elements? How can I give each of the child elements a class.

Comment: by child do you mean `<path>`?